# Bootstrap Date Time picker is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have been trying to use the bootstrap Date and time picker. I dont know whats wrong with the code. though its very simple.
I tried to include the datepicker jar manually and with CDN.
Still its not working.

Can any body help me with this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.bs.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your bootstrap-datepicker.bs.min.js. It seems you are missing a js file. Try inspect and you will see error in console that datetimepicker() is not a function.

Comment: you are right.. I tried multiple CDN though its not working.. can you provide me some link for the CDN.. Sorry for being DUMB

Comment: I have added it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Datetimepicker CDN. Below CDN seems to work for me:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
```

Working Plnkr: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DHjvcfe2IkTUAzCT5yOU?p=preview)

Comment: copy and pasted your whole code.. But still I am getting TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
 

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

Comment: @varun you must be trying on your local machine for that need to prefix http: in js and css files paths else it tries to find a file which doesn't exist hence the error. You can copy paste now, I have updated the Plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a problem referencing the script files.

Update the scripts to this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrmbe7pg/)